# Erro de troca de imagens no botão dropdown

Tags: javascript, css3, bootstrap-3

Olá.
Tenho um menu dropdown (bootstrap 3.3.7) que possui duas imagens que a troca delas é feita via css.
Quando o menu está ativo o botão módulo não deveria ficar cinza e sim branco.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa abaixo está correta.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML com PHP que chama o menu

```css
/* Início Botão Módulos */
  .BotaoModulos
{
  background-image: url('../img/icones/new2/modulos_out.png');
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 40px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  color: #8B92B1 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family:sans-serif !important;
}
.BotaoModulos li img
{
  display: block;
}
.BotaoModulos:hover
{
  background-image: url('../img/icones/new2/modulos_in.png');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family:sans-serif !important;
}
/* Fim Botão Módulos */

.LinkFav1_PF
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  width: 90px;
  height: 75px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #8B92B1 !important;
}

.LinkFav1_PF:hover
{
  background: rgba(249, 166, 74, 1);
  /*top: -1px;
  padding-top: 1px; */
  color: #fff !important;
  width: 90px;
  height: 75px;
}
.LinkFav1_PF:active ul li
{
  color: #fff;
}

.MenuInfFav
{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-1 MenuFav LinkFav1_PF" style="margin-top: -1px;">
      <ul>
          <li class="BotaoModulos">teste
          <!-- Aqui eu tenho uma chamada PHP para o menu-left-1.ctp -->       
          </li>
      </ul>
</div>
<!-- O código abaixo é o menu que é chamado pelo código acima -->
<!-- Menu-left-1 = Prover -->

<div class="dropdown" style="border: 0px !important; border-radius: 0px;  ">
  <a class="BotaoModulos dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="TextMenuFav" style="margin-top: 7px">Módulos</span>
  </a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"  style="margin: 3.3px -88px 0 !important; border-radius: 0px; background-color: #FAD88D;">

        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List UsersProfiles'), ['controller' => 'UsersProfiles', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Profiles'), ['controller' => 'Profiles', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Models'), ['controller' => 'Models', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>

        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Groups'), ['controller' => 'Groups', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Maintainers'), ['controller' => 'Maintainers', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Institutions'), ['controller' => 'Institutions', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Campuses'), ['controller' => 'Campuses', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Courses'), ['controller' => 'Courses', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Semesters'), ['controller' => 'Semesters', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>

        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Financing Plans'), ['controller' => 'FinancingPlans', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
        </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução CSS é utilizar o  estado "focus", ficando assim:

```
.BotaoModulos:hover, .BotaoModulos:focus
{
  background-image: url('../img/icones/new2/modulos_in.png');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family:sans-serif !important;
}
```

Único problema é que quando vc clicar fora, ele perderá o estado "focus", aí teria que utilizar Javascript pra adicionar/remover uma classe no click, porém como vc está usando o Bootstrap, se não me engano, o dropdown fecha quando clica fora, então deve servir..

Comment: Fiz isso mas não consegui.
Como seria essa questão do js que vc disse?